# App delegate has no member persistentStoreCoordinator (remove from core data, swift)

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

Hi I want to remove a row from core data. I was able to remove the item from the table, but not from core data. A lot of places give the same answer to this question. But after struggling for hours and seeing all links from the first 20 pages of google search results, it is still not working.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        foodItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedObjectContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let coord = delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator // App delegate has no member persistentStoreCoordinator

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ProductName")
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)

    do {
        try coord.executeRequest(deleteRequest, withContext: managedObjectContext)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        debugPrint(error)
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my answer -- you don't need to save batch deletes. But, you do need to reload any in-memory objects.  This is presuming that your fetch request is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The docs tell you how to update your in-memory objects: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html

> make sure the resultType of the NSBatchDeleteRequest is set to NSBatchDeleteRequestResultType.resultTypeObjectIDs before the request is executed.

```
do {
    let result = try moc.execute(request) as? NSBatchDeleteResult
    let objectIDArray = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID]
    let changes = [NSDeletedObjectsKey : objectIDArray]
    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave(changes, [moc])
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to perform batch update: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Where? why? and how is that going to solve the error?

Comment: In CoreData, the context has in-memory objects representing the rows.  When you do a batch delete, it goes directly to the underlying store (doesn't change the context) You get back ids of objects and you need to tell the context to remove them from the context. Also, if you have references to managed objects you need to check if they are deleted. Where? after executeRequest.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here. You want to delete an entry. You need the managed object context, which you are already getting:

```
let managedObjectContext = delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

You then appear to be trying to get an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, which you don't need, and which causes your error message:

```
let coord = delegate.persistentStoreCoordinator // App delegate has no member persistentStoreCoordinator
```

You're getting this error message because your app delegate doesn't have a property called `persistentStoreCoordinator`. It's exactly as obvious as the error message sounds.

I'm not completely sure why you're trying to get a persistent store coordinator-- possibly because you're also trying to use a batch delete request even though you say you just want to delete a single row:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ProductName")
let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
```

If you run that request and it succeeds, you will delete **every instance of `ProductName`**, not just the one row. You're not telling the request to filter the objects and find only one (or a few). Instead you've set up a batch request that will hit every single instance instead of the selected row.

You could fix the batch request by adding a predicate, but that would be a very unusual way to delete a single row. Generally, you fetch a bunch of managed objects, and if you want to delete one, you tell the managed object to delete that object. There's no need for a batch request on a single object.

If your `foodItems` array contains instances of `NSManagedObject` (or subclasses of `NSManagedObject`), a better approach would be to use the managed object context, which has a `delete` method. Get the object at `foodItems[indexPath.row]` and pass it directly to the `delete` method.